# cannot see any files in google compute engine ftp server

Tags: ftp, google-cloud-platform

I setup vsftpd on a google compute engine instance. I can ftp into the /home/user directory I created for my user and I can also view subdirectories from my remote ftp client. I cannot however see any files within any of the folders. Why might this be?

I am using the following /etc/vsftp file. 
The directory in local_root=/srv/ftp does not seem to be created either.

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO  # do not allow unidentified user to login
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES  # allow writes
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES

user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/srv/ftp # define your ftp directory
chroot_local_user=YES  # will chroot all the users
chroot_list_enable=NO  # select YES if you would like to specify usernames in /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list 
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/server.key
ssl_enable=no

pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
```